# SQL. Trying to create a stored procedure on SQL, but not sure if I have the right query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Create a SQL stored procedure that parses a string into previously unknown number of fields.  The inputs would be

1. a text string of undetermined length;
2. a delimiter, passed as a string;
3. a nullable column that, if relevant, would pass the text indicator as a single character string.

The resulting table would be entirely dependent on the string used as an input

Please help because I cannot figure this out. I know this is wrong, but I had no clue where to begin.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @l INT, @c VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @l = MAX(LEN(n)) FROM AdventureWOrk
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

;WITH cte AS


)

Insert INTO @Values (1, 'CGID', 'EENumber', 'EEYID', 'SSN' )   
SELECT
[Value], 
[Value],
Prod_Attributes.value('/Attribute[1]','varchar(MAX)') AS [CGID],
Prod_Attributes.value('/Attribute[2]','varchar(MAX)') AS [EENUMBER], 
Prod_Attributes.value('/Attribute[3]','varchar(MAX') AS [EYEID], 
Prod_Attributes.value('/Attribute[4]','varchar(MAX') AS [SSN]
```

Comment: PLEASE use [MSDN - Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for syntax requirements FIRST before posting. Not only does MSDN beat any other documentation out there, but you will know what the terminology is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure by using the following syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_YourProcedure
AS 
BEGIN
  -- Your logic
END
```

You would put the code you already have within the `BEGIN` statement.

To execute the stored procedure you can do:

```
EXEC usp_YourProcedure
```

To add parameters, simply state them after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` declaration.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_YourProcedure
(
    @TextField  VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @Delimeter  VARCHAR(1),
    @TextIndicator CHAR(1) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

END
```

Then to execute with parameters:

```
EXEC usp_YourProcedure  'String literal, with commas, which will, be stripped out by the delimiter', ','
```

Further details are outlined at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms345415.aspx).

As an additional note, try keeping your variable names descriptive and consistent, also check the casing.

Comment: Thank you for your help! How do I do the last step? The nullable field part

Comment: @MavsNation - you're welcome.  Simply add `NULL` as the default value as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <ProcedureName> 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    <Param1>, <Param2> ...
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
END
GO
```